# How to print message in the terminal?

Tags: java, spring, terminal

I am writing java code using Spring framework. I am trying to debug my code.  I know that in the IDE, I can use "system.out.println" to print message in the console, I am wondering how do I do to print message in the terminal when I am running the integration test? Otherwise I cannot debug.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: potentially (realistically) your Spring application (web??) will not have a console.  It may uses log4j or other logging system to log to a file - you can debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the test on IDE then use "system.out.println" to print message in the console. But you want to run test on server you can use logger for that i.e log4j or slf4j.

for log4j you can refer this link
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/